# L6218E: Undefined symbol IoTHubMessage_IsSecurityMessage

Tags: c++, c, azure, mbed

I am trying to connect azure via LTE with the Ublox module C030-R412m. I'm programming it through Mbed Studio, and I haven't even managed to compile the azure iot hub libraries.

I am trying to compile the main which contains the following function:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "iothub_message.h"

// main () runs in its own thread in the OS
int main ()
{
    IOTHUB_MESSAGE_HANDLE messageHandle;
    
    IoTHubMessage_IsSecurityMessage (messageHandle);
}
```

And it generates the following error:

```
Building project mbed-os-empty-5 (UBLOX_C030_R412M, ARMC6)
Scan: mbed-os-empty-5
Link: mbed-os-empty-5
[Warning] @ 0,0: L3912W: Option 'legacyalign' is deprecated.
[Error] @ 0,0: L6218E: Undefined symbol IoTHubMessage_IsSecurityMessage (referred from BUILD / UBLOX_C030_R412M / ARMC6 / main.o).
Warning: L3912W: Option 'legacyalign' is deprecated.
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol IoTHubMessage_IsSecurityMessage (referred from BUILD / UBLOX_C030_R412M / ARMC6 / main.o).
Finished: 0 information, 1 warning and 1 error messages.
[ERROR] Warning: L3912W: Option 'legacyalign' is deprecated.
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol IoTHubMessage_IsSecurityMessage (referred from BUILD / UBLOX_C030_R412M / ARMC6 / main.o).
Finished: 0 information, 1 warning and 1 error messages.
```

[image: The project contains the following files]

The libraries have been downloaded from each of the Github repositories, the only thing that I have modified is that from the umock-c repository I have only put the mock_c_prod.h library at the root folder as can be seen in the previous image.

Comment: Have you linked the libraries correctly? Please check the if the library paths (libraries and header files) are included in the system path.

Comment: Can you explain me how can i include libraries in the system path in Windows 10?

Comment: Likewise, the libraries are included in the code manually

Comment: Maybe set the `PATH` variable in the Environment variables.

Comment: Solve: MbedStudio->View->Libraries, and there include the libraries from the main menu, or modify the currents.

Comment: If this question is solved, can you please post an answer explaining your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, if you get that error it is a problem with the libraries.
What should be done is:

Or include the libraries in the PATH, which is more complicated.

Or the easiest thing is to go to the View-> Libraries menu, all the available libraries will appear there, all you have to do is:

Hit the "sum" icon to include the libraries. And in case you want to update the library to a previous or later version, you would have to give the icon of the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdFMn.png) and then put: "Check out to version". And choose the version that suits us best.